# MySQL user defined function error

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a user defined function that will take a user ID as an argument and then display the retailPrice column for that particular row. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION itemPrice(uId DECIMAL(8,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE r DECIMAL(8,2)
    SELECT INTO retailPrice r FROM item WHERE userId = uId;
    RETURN(r);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `SELECT retailPrice INTO r`

Comment: You also need a `;` at the end of the `DECLARE` line.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;` between the `DECLARE` statement and the `SELECT` query. And you have `INTO` in the wrong place in the query.

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE FUNCTION itemPrice(uId DECIMAL(8,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE r DECIMAL(8,2);
    SELECT retailPrice INTO r FROM item WHERE userId = uId;
    RETURN(r);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```